# How do use a piece of state in two different components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I have an issue where I have a React component where I need to use a function in two different spots.

The function is called 'handleBotAttackClick'.

I need to use it in the Header and the ShowAttackStats methods you see below.

All the state stuff is defined in Header.

But since 'handleBotAttackClick' is defined in Header, it shows up undefined in ShowAttackStats.

Is there a way to reconcile this so that both can use it successfully?

Thanks!

```
const ShowAttackStats = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <span>
                < a href="#" onClick={handleBotAttackClick}>Show All Stats</a>
            </span>
        </>
    );
}

const Header = () => {

    const [showAttackScreen, setAttackScreen] = useState(false);

    const handleBotAttackClick = useCallback(e => { setAttackScreen(true) });

    return (

            <div>
                <p> {showAttackScreen && <showAttackStats />}
            </div>

            <div>
                <p> {showAttackScreen && <AttackScreenGrid />}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Hi there! The best way to handle this is by using a state manager. I will advise you should go with the  context API.

Comment: @SiradjiAwoual Hi thanks, but isn't there a way to do it with just React and not an extra API?  I only need to do it for this one part.  Thanks

Comment: a context api is a bit much since the markup is really simple. use `handleBotAttackClick ` as callback when `ShowAttackStats` dispatches an event

Comment: You can [lift state up](https://dev.to/akhildhiman/lifting-state-up-35ki) and if prop drilling becomes a problem then you can use context.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell actually, context API is part of react. It's just like redux albeit much smaller.

Comment: @HMR hi thanks, I visited the link but I’m not sure how that would help me.. but thank you

Comment: @SiradjiAwoual oh it is? How could I use that to help me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const ShowAttackStats = ({ onClick }) => {
    function handleClick(ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
     onClick && onClick()
    }

    return (
        <>
            <span>
                < a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>Show All Stats</a>
            </span>
        </>
    );
}
```

Your header

```
const Header = () => {

    const [showAttackScreen, setAttackScreen] = useState(false);

    const handleBotAttackClick = useCallback(e => { setAttackScreen(true) });

    return (

            <div>
                <p> {showAttackScreen && <ShowAttackStats onClick={handleBotAttackClick} />}
            </div>

            <div>
                <p> {showAttackScreen && <AttackScreenGrid onSomeAction={handleBotAttackClick}/>}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: So it partially works.  It's showing the bottom component, which is AttackScreenGrid, but it's not showing ShowAttackStats.